# VBA-Add formula with variable as double

Tags: vba, variables, decimal

I am trying to add formula to a cell with variable having decimal points. however when i am using 'Double' data types i am getting a 'run-time error:1004 application  or object defined   error.
However when I am using 'Long' as datatypes there are no error but the values are wrong. Below is the code I am trying out.

```
Sub copy_data_to_sheets()


Dim Mat As String
Dim Angle As String
Dim lo As Double
Dim ao As Double
Dim bo As double
Dim so As double
Dim Strformula As String

For i = 1 To 1 Step 1 'Moving across diferent sheets
    Worksheets("Probe" & Chr(32) & i).Activate

With ActiveSheet

Range("F1:N10000").ClearContents 'Delete out Previous data

Mat = Worksheets("Ergebnisse").Cells(i + 3, 2).Value
Angle = Worksheets("Ergebnisse").Cells(i + 3, 3).Value
lo = 80
ao = Worksheets("Ergebnisse").Cells(i + 3, 4).Value
bo = Worksheets("Ergebnisse").Cells(i + 3, 5).Value
so = Worksheets("Ergebnisse").Cells(i + 3, 6).Value

    Noofrows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Count total no of Rows with data(Lotid)
    NoofColumns = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Count total no of Columns with data
    'MsgBox "Total no of rows " & Noofrows

Range("F3") = "Thickness change"
Range("F4") = "mm"
Strformula = "=-" & ao & "*(B5/" & lo & "+C5/" & bo & ")"
Range("F5").Formula = Strformula 'Error with decimal points
Range("F5:F" & Noofrows).FillDown

End With

 Next i
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting error in the above code?

Comment: Probably you are not using English locale with `.` as decimal code? `.Formula` expect the formula to be written in English. You can either use `.FormulaLocal` to use a localized formula, or force the double to string conversion to use US format using `Str(ao)`.

Comment: @Nagarajan N D : i am getting error when i am adding the fomula to the range,i.e, "Range("F5").Formula = Strformula 'Error with decimal points"

Comment: @Vincent G : Tried it..got resolved. Thanks